# MergeSort, Java Code not working?

Tags: java, mergesort

The Merging function:

```
static int[] merge(int v[], int start, int middle, int end){
    int i = start, temp, j = middle, k = 0;

    int a[] = new int[end];
    while(j < end && i < middle){
        if(v[i] > v[j]){
            a[k++] = v[j++];
        }
        else{
            a[k++] = v[i++];
        }
    }
    for(temp = i; temp < middle; temp++){
        a[k++] = v[temp];
    }
    for(temp = j; temp < end; temp++){
        a[k++] = v[temp];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < end; i++)
        v[i] = a[i];
    return v;
}
```

The Splitting Function:

```
static int[] split(int v[], int start, int end){
    int array[] = new int[end-start+1];
    for(int i = start, j = 0; i <= end; i++, j++){
        array[j] = v[i];
    }
    return array;
}
```

The MergeSort Function:

```
static int[] mergesort(int v[], int start, int end) {
    int middle = v.length/2, left, right;
    if(end-start <= 1){
        return v;
    }
    mergesort(split(v, start, middle), start, middle);
    mergesort(split(v, middle+1, end-1), middle+1, end-1);
    merge(v, start, middle, end);
    return v;
}
```

The Main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int v[] = {6,1,8,2,9,3};
    int end = 6, i;
    v = mergesort(v, 0, end);
    for(i = 0; i < end; i++){
        System.out.print(v[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output given is 2 6 1 8 9 3 and should be 1 2 3 6 8 9

I'm pretty sure it's here:

```
mergesort(split(v, start, middle), start, middle);
mergesort(split(v, middle+1, end-1), middle+1, end-1);
merge(v, start, middle, end);
```

these functions return an array but what can i assign it to ?

Comment: *what's wrong*: that's what **you** should tell us. What are you doing, what behavior are you expecting, and what behavior are you observing instead?

Comment: Does it help you, if i post my merge sort, even though it uses a list as input? There is just a finished solution in my eclipse projects.

Comment: It couldn't hurt! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, which is using lists instead of arrays.

```
public <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> mergeSort(List<E> unsortedList) {

    if (unsortedList == null || unsortedList.size() < 2) {
        return unsortedList;
    } else {
        List<E> left = new LinkedList<E>();
        List<E> right = new LinkedList<E>();

        int pivot = (1 + unsortedList.size()) / 2;

        while (!unsortedList.isEmpty()) {
            if (pivot > 0) {
                left.add(unsortedList.remove(0));

                pivot--;
            } else {
                right.add(unsortedList.remove(0));
            }
        }
        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);

        return merge(left, right);
    }
}

private <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> merge(List<E> left, List<E> right) {
    List<E> sortedResult = new ArrayList<E>(left.size() + right.size());

    while (!left.isEmpty() && !right.isEmpty()) {
        E leftElem, rightElem;

        leftElem = left.get(0);
        rightElem = right.get(0);

        if (leftElem.compareTo(rightElem) < 0) {
            sortedResult.add(leftElem);

            left.remove(0);
        } else {
            sortedResult.add(rightElem);

            right.remove(0);
        }
    }
    sortedResult.addAll(left);
    sortedResult.addAll(right);

    return sortedResult;
}
```

**INPUT:**

> [6, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1, 9, 8, 7, 8]

**OUTPUT:**

> [1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]

Comment: The thing about just posting a solution like that is that you haven't answered why the OP's code didn't work, and the OP loses a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating a little bit your code. Here is an alternative implementation. Let me know if it works:

```
class MergeSort2{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            int[] arrayToMerge = new int[]{45,66,7,8,444,3,5,66,7,1,9,3,55,6,7};

            mergeSort(arrayToMerge, 0 , arrayToMerge.length-1);

            for(int i=0; i < arrayToMerge.length; i++){
                System.out.println(" -> " + arrayToMerge[i]);
            }
        }

        public static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int start, int end){

            if(start < end){
                int mid = (start + end) /2;
                mergeSort(arr,start, mid);
                mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end);
                mergeArray(arr, start, mid, end);
            }

        }


        public static void mergeArray(int[] arr, int start, int mid, int  end){

            int[] temp = new int[end - start + 1];

            int i= start, j = mid + 1 , k = 0;

            while(i <= mid && j <= end){

                if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
                    temp[k] = arr[i];
                    k++;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                 {
                     temp[k] = arr[j];
                     k++;
                     j++;
                 }
            }

            while(i <= mid){
                temp[k] = arr[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }

            while (j <= end){
                temp[k] = arr[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        i= start;
            k=0;
            while (k < temp.length && i <= end){
                arr[i] = temp[k];
                i++;
                k++;
                }
        }
    }
```